# CSS background div behind another div

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to put a grid pattern behind some `<divs>`, like shown in the following (https://jsfiddle.net/4e5mcmk4/25/):

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="childA"></div>
    <div id="childB">
        hello
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
body {
    background:
        linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .03) 1px, transparent 1px),
        linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .03) 1px, transparent 1px),
        linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .03) 1px, transparent 1px),
        linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .03) 1px, transparent 1px),
        linear-gradient(transparent 3px, transparent 3px, transparent 78px, transparent 78px),
        linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent 1px, transparent 1px),
        linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent 3px, transparent 3px, transparent 78px, transparent 78px),
        linear-gradient(transparent 1px, transparent 1px), transparent;
    background-size:
        10px 10px,
        10px 10px,
        10px 10px,
        10px 10px,
        10px 10px,
        10px 10px,
        10px 10px,
        10px 10px;
}
```

This is the look I am going for, but instead of applying this CSS rule to body, I want "#childA" to fill the parent (and parent to fill body), and apply the same background. More generally, I want a full-size div to appear underneath its sibling div.

However, I can't seem to get parent, childA, or childB to expand to fill the space of the div.

Any suggestions?

Comment: grid applied as the background of #childA (rather than background of body), and grid shows up behind the text from childB.

Comment: Change CSS `body` to `#parent`, and add `height: 100vh;`:  https://jsfiddle.net/jkcs2L94/  Don't know what you mean by "I want a full-size div to appear underneath its sibling div."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need then is to set the `width` and `height` of the parent while applying the background property

```
#parent{
background:
    linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .03) 1px, transparent 1px),
    linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .03) 1px, transparent 1px),
    linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .03) 1px, transparent 1px),
    linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .03) 1px, transparent 1px),
    linear-gradient(transparent 3px, transparent 3px, transparent 78px, transparent 78px),
    linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent 1px, transparent 1px),
    linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent 3px, transparent 3px, transparent 78px, transparent 78px),
    linear-gradient(transparent 1px, transparent 1px), transparent;
background-size:
    10px 10px,
    10px 10px,
    10px 10px,
    10px 10px,
    10px 10px,
    10px 10px,
    10px 10px,
    10px 10px;
    width:100%;
   height:100%;
   position:absolute;
}


#childA{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

I added position absolute because it has no parent with a fixed width

https://jsfiddle.net/4e5mcmk4/27/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are going for? http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/e9ypqy5t/12/

```
#parent{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100vh;
}
#childA{
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
    background:
        linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .03) 1px, transparent 1px),
        linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .03) 1px, transparent 1px),
        linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .03) 1px, transparent 1px),
        linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .03) 1px, transparent 1px),
        linear-gradient(transparent 3px, transparent 3px, transparent 78px, transparent 78px),
        linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent 1px, transparent 1px),
        linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent 3px, transparent 3px, transparent 78px, transparent 78px),
        linear-gradient(transparent 1px, transparent 1px), transparent;
    background-size:
        10px 10px,
        10px 10px,
        10px 10px,
        10px 10px,
        10px 10px,
        10px 10px,
        10px 10px,
        10px 10px;

}
#childB{width: 100%; height: 20px; background-color: lightblue;}
```